# Select shop type using Shopify API

Tags: api, e-commerce, shopify

I'm a developer who uses Shopify Developer API. I searched API, trying to find method to retrieve information about shop business industry.
I didn't find anything. I've tried to get this information from Metafield API from store, but I've found just information about pos_attributes.
Could you help me to solve this issue? (In general, is it possible or not?)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that is not possible. The information you've shown is only for Shopify to tailor some stuff for your usage and it is no where linked to your account in the accessible fields.

Fortunately, you can always add custom meta-fields (information fields) to the Shopify store using the Metafield API and retrieve it at anytime anywhere.

Use the Metafield API to POST the following information directly on the store url - *https://****your_store_name****.myshopify.com/admin/metafields.json*

```
{
    "metafield": {
        "namespace": "meta",                   //any string will work
        "key": "industry",                     //any string will work
        "value": "Leather Manufacturing",      // A string or a number
        "value_type": "string"                 //accepted values are string & integer
    }
}
```

Once stored, you can call it on the shop using Metafield object property. `{{ shop.metafields.namespace.key.}}` (in this case `{{ shop.metafields.meta.industry }}`)

And if you want to call it using the API use GET with the url - *https://****your_store_name****.myshopify.com/admin/metafields/****metafield_id****.json*

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I'm a little bit confused, when I created new affilate store under my Shopify Developer account, I selected product type what I sell: http://prntscr.com/944q6l . Is it possible to retrieve this information via Shopify API?

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible. The information you've shown is only for Shopify to tailor some stuff for your usage and it is no where linked to your account in the accessible fields. If you can tell what exactly you are looking to implement I can point you in the right direction.

Comment: I just want to develop simple plugin and I would like to show after installation process as full as possible information about shop on preview page. Business industry is one of the main properties, which helps to describe store, I selected product type, that's why I expected to get this info back. Well, then, we're not fated to. Sorry, for interaption. You can create answer from your last comment and I'll accept it as right answer.

Comment: I have updated the current answer including the comment. I'd advise you use metafields for your purpose. It sounds trivial but a lot of apps put this work around to very good uses.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. The main problem is that my application has to work with many shops every with own metadata. I can't rely on this.

Comment: Are you planning to display Business industry information on the pages of the shop?

Comment: Yes, I'm planning to show Business industry information on plugin settings page. I expect, that shop will donwload my app from Shopify AppStore. I don't have a chance to bind to some particular shops and their meta-information.

Comment: Well you can always let the merchants pick the industry initially as soon as they installs your app. Once picked, you can make your app write that into their store metadata.